# Batch File to Delete result* Folders from Subfolders

Tags: batch-file, subdirectory

I have a folder structure set up like so:

```
C:/Scripts
C:/Scripts/Script1
C:/Scripts/Script1/result2
C:/Scripts/Script1/result5
C:/Scripts/Script1/result1
C:/Scripts/Script2
C:/Scripts/Script2/result10
C:/Scripts/Script2/result7
C:/Scripts/Script3
C:/Scripts/Script3/result1
C:/Scripts/Script4
```

I'm looking to create a batch file I could keep in the `C:/Scripts/` directory which would look in each of its subfolders (e.g. `Script1`, `Script2`, `Script3`, etc), and delete any folders within them (any files inside) that starts with `result` (e.g. `result1`, `result2`, `result3`, etc). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r "C:\Scripts" %%d in (.) do (
  set "name=%%~nxd"
  if /i "!name:~0,6!"=="result" rd /s /q "%%~d"
)
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Just so the OP knows, it may work fine in this situation but it will also delete `c:\scripts\result` if that folder ever exists.